# How to get the div id and use it in mysql data manipulation in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a web page with a tab button from monday to saturday. By clicking one of the tabs, the resulting table should display values according by their day. Can it be achieve?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. You can use just a plain `php`. Or style it with easier loading by using `ajax` and `javascript`.

Comment: Yes it can. It's the power of PHP.

Comment: Can I ask for the code?

Comment: Uhm.. Well, no. The community of this website will just help you with your problems in programming, but asking for a whole code is just too much. What you can do is to update your post, put in the code you are currently working on, explain it, and we, at this community, will try to understand and help you with your problem. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div id is a part of the client-side rendered page. To get server-side functionality like a database insert you would first need to transmit the div id to the server, either using a html form or an ajax call.

Definitely possible although I'd recommend consulting some tutorials on the subject first.

Comment: I know how to get data from a form using post but I don;t know to get data from a div...

Comment: You could use Javascript to populate a hidden input form element. E.g. using jQuery's .click() event handler to populate an input and submit the form via ajax.

Comment: I will try that first.